# URL Rewriting don't work in my apache2

Tags: php, apache, url, url-rewriting

I have a problem with my apache2, the url rewriting don't work and I don't know why...

In my phpinfo(), I have:

```
Loaded Modules: mod_rewrite
```

My .htaccess:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^test\.html$ /test.php [L]
```

My Apache config:

```
<VirtualHost>
        ServerAdmin mail@gmail.com
        ServerName www.site.com
        ServerAlias site.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/site.com/

        <Directory />
                Options FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride All
        </Directory>
        <Directory /var/www/site.com/>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride All
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
        </Directory>

        ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
        <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
                AllowOverride All
                Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
                Order allow,deny
                Allow from all
        </Directory>

        ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/error.log

        # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
        # alert, emerg.
        LogLevel warn

        CustomLog /var/log/apache2/access.log combined

    Alias /doc/ "/usr/share/doc/"
    <Directory "/usr/share/doc/">
        Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Order deny,allow
        Deny from all
        Allow from 127.0.0.0/255.0.0.0 ::1/128
    </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

I think my config is right, but I really don't know why my rewriting don't work... Have you an idea ?

Thanks you so much !

Answer (score 1):

For this particular rule:

```
RewriteRule ^test\.html$ /test.php [L]
```

Mod_negotiation is going to try to deal with it for you. You want to turn `Multiviews off` if you want that to work:

```
Options -Multiviews
```

at the top of your htaccess file, or remove it from your `<Directory>` container:

```
    <Directory /var/www/site.com/>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride All
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
    </Directory>
```

Comment: Thanks you Jon Lin. I have deleted the "Multiviews" word of my vhost. But when I go to my page: http://www.site.com/test.php, the url is always such (http://www.site.com/test.php)... 

I have restarted the service (service apache2 restart), but the url rewriting don't work...

Comment: @Dimi Your rule takes the URL `/test.html` and internally rewrites it to `/test.php`, not the other way around. The rule does nothing if you request `/test.php`.